# AS3 Change Frame/Instance within MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am not a programmer, so please forgive me if my question is too noobish.

I created a MovieClip in my library called "skill". Then I added three instances of that MovieClip into my stage called "skill_01", "skill_02", and "skill_03" respectively. I selected all three instances and created another MovieClip called "diagram" to nest them inside it. I will later add more skill instances inside this MovieClip called "diagram" but for now, I need the basics to work with three instances.

The main timeline or stage only has 1 frame, and so does the "diagram" MovieClip instance. However, the skill instances all have two frames: in frame 1 I have an PNG image showing them as being locked/offline, and in frame 2 I have another PNG showing them as unlocked/online. **I need to be able to toggle them by clicking and right clicking on them, just like in the example below (see link)**

I am trying to make it so that when you left click the skill instances they toggle to Online/Unlocked by switching to the PNG image in frame 2, and when you right click them, it goes back to frame 1 (Offline/Locked). I've tried several different lines of code, including the ones recommended by Adobe itself, and others, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It will go to frame 2 and refuse to go back to frame 1 when right clicked.

This is the code I have in the MovieClip:

```
stop();
skill_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

This part of the code doesn't work:

```
skill_01a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToPreviousFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToPreviousFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  prevFrame();
}
```

Screenshot 1: 
gyazo (dot) com/e622baee46c3fabbd8c9a8d2df8396fe

Screenshot 2: 
gyazo (dot) com/1b360716a5d243aa74e2be4127fe9a5b

(Sorry for typing the links like that, it won't let me add more than 1 link because I just signed up to this Forum)

For more context, I am trying to make a Skill Tree, that works similar to this one: http://www.dungeonsanddevelopers.com/#__6_Your

I will appreciate any help figuring this out!

Comment: can you explain that what is the second code block ? and where is it added? and also what is skill_01a ('a'  suffix)

Comment: the first block makes the movieclip jump to frame 2 when clicked
the second block is supposed to make the movieclip jump back to frame 1 when right clicked

skill_01 is the instance in frame 1 and skill_01a is the instance in frame 2

Comment: that is completely wrong. Try rewriting them again like me. You have to control that button from out (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

if you have named your movieclip, skill_01, so what is the skill_01a ?

also add your event listener and its callback function in to the movieclip's parent and inside the callback function, for accessing the event owner, use

```
// stop(); not necessary to call stop if you have only 1 frame

with (this.diagram) {
  skill_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);
  skill_02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);
  skill_03.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);
  skill_04.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);
  skill_01.gotoAndStop(1);
  skill_02.gotoAndStop(1);
  skill_03.gotoAndStop(1);
  skill_04.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (MovieClip(event.target.parent).currentFrame == 1)
    MovieClip(event.target.parent).gotoAndStop(2);
  else
    MovieClip(event.target.parent).gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

**Edit:** when an event is dispatched from clicked movieclip, only the last movieclip inside hierarchy tree will be passed as `event.target` in your exaple, that can be skill_01 (if currentframe is 1) or skill_1a (if currentframe is 2) athwart the question body, you have not only a png image inside skill's frame 1 and 2, they are movieclip's and will be returned as event.target. but if you only put your bitmaps (locked.png & unlocked.png) instead of skill_01 and skill_01a, the previous code works fine. bitmaps does not capture event so its parent is who accepted click event and its all a little confusing, i'm not good at explain

if its hard to comprehend

### we shall use some thing like it, easier but larger code

```
with (this.diagram) {
  skill_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s1);
  skill_02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s2);
  skill_03.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s3);
  skill_04.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s4);
  skill_01.gotoAndStop(1);
  skill_02.gotoAndStop(1);
  skill_03.gotoAndStop(1);
  skill_04.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s1(event:MouseEvent):void {
 toggle_buttons(skill_01);
}
function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s2(event:MouseEvent):void {
 toggle_buttons(skill_02);
}
function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s3(event:MouseEvent):void {
 toggle_buttons(skill_03);
}
function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_s4(event:MouseEvent):void {
 toggle_buttons(skill_04);
}

function toggle_buttons(button:MovieClip):void
{
  if (button.currentFrame == 1)
    button.gotoAndStop(2);
  else
    button.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the program runs without errors, but nothing happens when I click on the MovieClip, it's not even going to frame 2 anymore

Comment: yes, the code is not complete, it was just a suggestion for that part which must be edited, let me  a second to complete it

Comment: the code preferred must be copied to main time line, an instance of button Movieclip could be exists in stage and must be named skill_01, that's all, good luck

Comment: when I put the code inside the MovieClip instances nothing happens
when I put the code in the main time line, I get an error  "Access of undefined property skill_01"

https://gyazo.com/3198949d29c2e2e935e65a93517e263e

I'm having a hard time understanding what's wrong here...

Comment: @Nimvoker according my previous comment, you must have a movieclip, named skill_01 in your main stage, how many frames have you in main timeline?

Comment: I have a MovieClip in my library called "skill", from which I created instances in the stage called "skill_01", "skill_02", "skill_03" etc. These instances are nested inside another MovieClip called "diagram", which is in the main timeline/stage. The main timeline and the diagram MovieClip both have only 1 frame, but the skill instances have 2 frames: in frame 1 they have one PNG image and in frame 2 they have another PNG image for both locked and unlocked visual states that I want them to switch to upon being clicked.

Comment: @Nimvoker, humm. its ok now, try it, and also please edit your answer too, explain your secret Movieclip, diagram to make it clear.

Comment: I edited my original post, I hope it is a bit more clear now, please let me know! 

This is my hierarchy:
Timeline/stage › diagram › skill › skill_01

I've been putting the code inside "skill", should I put the code elsewhere?

Comment: @Nimvoke i checked out you screen shot again, its not true that you said "Timeline/stage › diagram › skill › skill_01" is it? it must be some thing like Timeline/stage › diagram  › skill_01 & Timeline/stage › diagram  › skill_02 & Timeline/stage › diagram  › skill_03, all of skill instance, must be included inside diagram and only has a unique name with numeric suffixes.

Comment: If by buttons you mean the movieclips then yes, but I haven't used any actual buttons. The reason I have the skills nested within diagram is because I am using code to move all skills around for navigation with keyboard arrows, because the skill tree will be larger than the stage/screen area. Also, I confess that I am confused as to why my skill_01, skill_02, and skill_03 instances are all inside an instance called skill. I was expecting the hierarchy to be "main › diagram › skill_01", but when I imported the skill instances it added the extra "skill" layer.

Comment: My original screenshot went up to "skill" where I was placing the code. If I double click the instance again, it goes one level deeper, here's a screenshot of that: 
https://gyazo.com/b0d398076dcf63d507ced3ff4ffaf24e

Comment: sorry i cant see your screen shots without using proxy, so i just check that later and find out you have realy a new movieclip in your library . i can offer two thing, 1) upload your FLA.  2) let me make it for you and you can find the mistake by self

Comment: Thank you Payam, Where should I upload the FLA? Also, can I befriend you?  (:

Comment: @Nimvoker answer edited :) i'll email you fixed FLA too